# IBM Mobilefirst 7.0 - Can we deploy IOS native code?

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

Currently I'm working on IBM Mobilefirst and estimote ibeacon Integration regrading that I found some sample code over Internet.

Can we deploy native IOS code on a mobilefirst. Could you please tell me steps to configure that native IOS App on a mobilefirst environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom Obj-C code to your Hybrid application using Cordova plug-ins.
You can also develop fully native apps and integrate the MFPF SDK.

Learn more in the MobileFirst Platform Developer Center: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-all-tutorials-7-0/